# AWS EC2 IP belongs to virtual machine or physical server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

If I run a server on EC2 instance (virtual server) and ping it I'll get some IP address. Does this IP belongs to virtual server or real physical server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address belongs to a network interface that is attached to your EC2 instance. A network interface or virtual network card can include the following attributes:

- A primary private IPv4 address from the IPv4 address range of your
  VPC
- One or more secondary private IPv4 addresses from the IPv4
  address range of your VPC
- One Elastic IP address (IPv4) per private IPv4 address
- One public IPv4 address
- One or more IPv6 addresses
- One or more security groups
- A MAC address
- A source/destination check flag
- A description

More reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html